# Laravel long running queue job picking by second worker

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I have problem with laravel long running process which is added to queue. Using database driver and supervisord. The problem is that after worker #1 picking this job it must do some heavy processing (from 5 to 20min long) and by that time worker #2 picking this job too! How to deal with this?

How I'm adding these long running jobs:

```
Artisan::queue('process:import', [
    'file' => $file_to_import->id,
]);
```

Current queue.php

```
'database' => [
    'driver' => 'database',
    'table' => 'jobs',
    'queue' => 'default',
    'retry_after' => 1800,
],
```

Currently I limited numproc to 1.

Current supervisor config

```
[program:laravel-worker-autoitbs]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/web/www/xxx/public_html/artisan queue:work database --memory=2048 --sleep=3 --tries=3 --timeout=0
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=web
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/web/www/xxx/logs/worker.log
```

Comment: Are you running them as scheduled tasks? You could try the [`onOneServer`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/scheduling#running-tasks-on-one-server) method. Not sure if it just works for different servers or also different workers.

Comment: I'm adding these jobs with Artisan::queue('process:import') and this job needs some time to finish, another worker coming and picking same ignoring that another one is already processing. So results is double or even triple server load.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the queue mechanism thinks your long running job is timed-out, thus releasing it back into the queue. This is then picked up by a second worker, which also attempts to process the job.

You specified `--timeout=0`, so the job itself will not time-out.

Maybe something else does time out before the job is done. For instance the database connect might be lost. Could you check the logs for any indication of time-outs?

Comment: Noup, this job does not using DB, just splitting large file into smaller chunks. The problem is with supervisor i think. I don't get any errors, PHP part itself is ok.