# Laravel multi server queue worker issue. A running job is getting picked up by another server and fails immediately

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, worker

I have a Laravel backend running on three nodes. There are some heavy jobs (Redis) which can run for several hours (new feature). The issue is that they keep failing. The error message is:

```
App\Jobs\ImportProducts has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out.
```

This happens only if multiple nodes are running the command

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=product-import --memory=3G --timeout=0
```

(managed by Supervisor)

I could reproduce this manually while running the `queue:work` command repeatedly on multiple nodes. Here is the output:

1. Server

```
[2021-09-22 20:29:52][qvBy1eX58WohhDmGcIyjjdjufabx8ooI] Processing: App\Jobs\ImportProducts
```

2. Server

```
[2021-09-22 20:31:24][qvBy1eX58WohhDmGcIyjjdjufabx8ooI] Processing: App\Jobs\ImportProducts
[2021-09-22 20:31:24][qvBy1eX58WohhDmGcIyjjdjufabx8ooI] Failed:     App\Jobs\ImportProducts
```

Why is the second server picking up a running job and how can I prevent this?

Here ist the queue config:

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

    'connections' => [
        // ...
        'product-import' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 86400,
            'block_for' => 10,
            'timeout' => 86400
        ],
    ],

    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

Here is the relevant part of the Job:

```
<?php

// ...

class ImportProducts extends Job implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    public $timeout = 0;
    
    // ...

    /**
     * The unique ID of the job.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function uniqueId()
    {
        return $this->Import->id;
    }

    // /**
    //  * Get the middleware the job should pass through.
    //  *
    //  * @return array
    //  */
    // public function middleware()
    // {
    //     return [new WithoutOverlapping($this->Import->cms->id)];
    // }

}
```

*NOTE*
I've seen this question:
[Laravel long running queue job picking by second worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627864/laravel-long-running-queue-job-picking-by-second-worker)
but I can not find any relevant timeout settings.

#### UPDATE

All Servers have sync time (ntp)

I tried different timeout setting (0, large number, within job, artisan flag) with no luck.

Also I just double checked Redis. I thought maybe there are multiple entries for the job, but there is only one entry.

I have no Idea what to do now.

Comment: I think, problem in  parrarerilism. Look here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#unique-jobs

Comment: Looks promising. I‘ll try and let you know. If that solves the issue, i would be happy to accept and upvote an answer ;)

Comment: Dang. Thare is no such thing for Laravel 7

Comment: @Maksim unfortunately that did not solve the issue

Comment: Have you looked at this issue https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/315 ? Are you sure you are not using the same Redis DB for another app? If nothing works, you could set up your own cache lock to prevent double run...

Comment: @Mtxz Yes, I've seen this issue. That's why I set up the NTP. But no luck. And no, there are no other apps using this Redis server.

Comment: Well, then I suggest implementing your own lock to prevent double fire. Still is strange that Laravel still has this issue

Comment: @Mtxz yes. I thought about a custom lock too. It's not a big deal. But it feels like a workaround. I'll wait for possible fix for now. If there is no fix in my case, I'll solve it by custom lock. BTW. There is no double fire in the sense of "the event is fired multiple times".

Comment: Yeah, but your job is running on multiple instances. Does the second worker take the job to throw a particular error?

Comment: Yes. The second worker takes the job and acts as it would immediately time out.

Comment: Please Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032919/laravel-job-dispatched-on-one-server-handled-on-another  if it can help you

Comment: @KudosIntech as far as I can see, it's not related. I have no issues to pick a job from the same queue on a different server.

Comment: Have you tried the `--tries=1` flag on the artisan command?

Comment: No I didn't. I'll try

Comment: @Mtxz sorry, it took some time. However, `--tries=1` did not work

Comment: Ok, worth it to try. Do your Jobs return any value at the end of the processing? If not, try to return a value.

Comment: @Mtxz I'll try. But to be honest, that makes not much sense. 1. an artisan generated job says `@return void` for the `handle()` method. 2. The second server picks the job anyways before the first one is even able to get the return value.

Comment: That's true... but i'm out of ideas ^^

Answer (score 0):

- Each JOB has some configured timeout you can either set timeout to a very high value. You can set job timeout in Job class

`public $timeout = 0;`

- Use job middleware to stop job overlapping https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#preventing-job-overlaps

Comment: I tried the timeout setting with no luck, also the overlapping middleware did not work

Comment: can you try adding a method  public function timeout()
    {
        return time() + 60 * 60*10; // 10 hours for now
    }

Comment: does not fix the issue

Comment: which version of Laravel you're using?

Comment: I've used 7 but upgraded to 8 to be able to use ShouldBeUnique. In both cases I had/have the same outcome

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm facing the exact issue. Trying the suggestions I've read in this thread hasn't helped yet. Did you ever figure this out?